# Change visual c++ application font

Tags: visual-c++, fonts, gdi

How to change font in all dialog forms in a visual c++ application?

I want to set Tahoma style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [font for a dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the resource it's created from.  I believe that'll change the font on all the standard controls as well.  If you have custom controls, you'll have to do additional work.

Note that if you want to have the font match the default UI font for the computer, then you can use a virtual font like "MS Shell Dlg 2" which will be mapped to Tahoma on XP, and Segoe UI on Vista+.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but i want to set a default font for the app.  Suddenly I must use custom controls in this project.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing font in each dialog of your application would be rather tedious job.
You can employ MFC to do it for you. 
Check InitInstance of your app. Look at AfxEnableControlContainer();
It is being called woithout any parameter even though AfxEnableControlContainer is declared as

```
void AFX_CDECL AfxEnableControlContainer(COccManager* pOccManager=NULL);
```

COccManager is a very interesting class and is used when has occ ( OLE custom controls) support, managing OLE container and site classes. All MFC applications are created by default with occ support. If you do not see AfxEnableControlContainer in the code generated by wizard, you do not have occ support enabled.

Anyway, instead using default occ implementation, use own and change it to change the font.
Derive class from COccManager. In this sample I call it CDlgOccManager. Override virtual PreCreateDialog:

```
virtual const DLGTEMPLATE* PreCreateDialog(_AFX_OCC_DIALOG_INFO* pOccDialogInfo,
    const DLGTEMPLATE* pOrigTemplate);
```

In the implementation:

```
const DLGTEMPLATE* CDlgOccManager::PreCreateDialog(_AFX_OCC_DIALOG_INFO* pOccDialogInfo, const DLGTEMPLATE* pOrigTemplate)
{
    CDialogTemplate RevisedTemplate(pOrigTemplate);
    // here replace font for the template
    RevisedTemplate.SetFont(_T("Tahoma"), -16);

    return COccManager::PreCreateDialog (pOccDialogInfo, (DLGTEMPLATE*)RevisedTemplate.Detach());
}
```

Now you are changin font for all dialogs. Remember changing AfxEnableControlContainer call:

```
PROCESS_LOCAL(CDlgOccManager, pManager);

BOOL CDlgFontChangeApp::InitInstance()
{
    AfxEnableControlContainer(pManager.GetData());
.
.
.
}
```

DO not forget to

```
#include "DlgOccManager.h"
```

For new verion of the MFC include afxdisp.h for older, occimpl.h for COccManager.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed something. It is not a blunder but it needs an explanation.
I have kept this code in my repository for a very, very, very long time.
It was a time when DLLs kept all data as global, making data available to all modules that loaded this dll. In order to force data to be stored in TLS area, I used PROCESS_LOCAL macro that expands to invoking CProcessLocal class that is still alive. 
You can remove this macro and replace it with:

```
BOOL CDlgFontChangeApp::InitInstance()
{
    CDlgOccManager* pManager = new CDlgOccManager();
    AfxEnableControlContainer(pManager);
.
.
.
}
```